# Input передать в js

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите почему id="summ" не передаётся в js (сильно не пенайте, знаю что постом или гетом передаётся, а вот почему не работает - не понимаю)

```
   <form> 
        <input required="" id="summ" type="text" /> 
      </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var summ = document.getElementById('summ');
        var err = "ERROR";  
            if (summ > 0) 
                  alert(summ);
                else alert(err);

</script>
```

Comment: вместо

    var summ = document.getElementById('summ');

попробуйте 

    var summ =  parseInt(document.getElementById('summ').value);

Comment: всё равно выводит ERROR

Comment: `parseInt(document.getElementById('summ').value)` возвращает NaN, потому что значение не задано. А NaN в сравнении с 0 возвращает false.

Comment: возможно потому, что этот скрипт исполняется при загрузке страницы, когда в поле ввода ничего нет. А Вы ожидаете, что оно выполниться, когда Вы нажмете на кнопку. Но JavaScript не такой умный, что бы это догадаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form> 
    <input required="" id="summ" type="text" /> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var summ = document.getElementById('summ');
console.log(summ); // это элемент
summ = +summ.value || 0; // получаем его значение числом
    var err = "ERROR";  
    if (summ > 0) 
        alert(summ);
    else
        alert(err);
</script>
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю, но я ввожу в инпут число 9, нажимаю энтер и выскакивает окошко ERROR...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/dwp77/

Comment: спасибо, примерно  понял

Comment: @нгш, по энтеру вы отправляете форму на ту же страницу. Страница загружается, значение сбрасывается.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim).

Когда вы пишите `var summ = document.getElementById('summ');` вы создаете ссылку на [dom-элемент](http://learn.javascript.ru/dom). У него очень много свойств и методов. Когда вы пишите то, что рекомендует [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), вы обращаетесь к свойству `value` элемента, какое вам и надо.

Answer (score 0):

Поле пусть будет с именем, а id лучше задать у формы. Так вы гарантируете, что при обычной отправке формы введённое значение попадёт на сервер и легко прочитается. Обязательно предусмотрите кнопку для отправки формы для тупых браузеров. Через CSS его можно скрыть.

```
<form id="sum_form">
   <input name="sum_val" type="text" />
   <input type="submit" value="&gt;"/>
</form>
```

Через [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) можно привязать к форме любую функцию, которая будет вызываться перед отправкой формы

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ // когда загрузится страница

    // к форме на событие отправки формы привязать обработчик
    $('#sum_form').on('submit',function(){

        // перед отправкой формы
        var val_sum_field = $(this).find('input[name=sum_val]'),
            val = parseFloat(val_sum_field.val());
        if (isNaN(val)) { // если в поле ввода не число, то ...
            alert('ERROR'); // пожаловаться ...
            return false; // и форму не отправлять
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Интересно, но пока наверно сложновато, я просто хотел сделать условие со всплывающем окошком, а у вас уже передается в адресную строку число